# Click event not recognizing textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

My click event is showing the error "the name login_password and login_username does not exist in the current context" when I am trying to access my text box from their ids. please help me identify the error as I am just a beginner.

**click event:**

```
protected void LogIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usern = "abc";
        string pass = "123";

        if (login_username.Text == usern && login_password.Text == pass)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        }
        else
        {

               label1.Text = "LogIn";                            
        }

    }
}
```

**login form:**

```
<form id="login" runat="server">
<h1 style = "Background-color: deepskyblue;">
    Log in to your account!</h1>
<p class="register">
    <a style = "color: deepskyblue;" href="Login.aspx?logoff=true">Logoff</a>
</p>
<div>
    <label for="login_username">
        Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="login_username" class="field required" title="Please provide your username" onclick="return login_username_onclick()" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="login_password">
        Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="login_password" class="field required"
        title="Password is required" />
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Log in" runat="server" OnClick="LogIn_Clicked" 
        BackColor="#00B2EE" ForeColor="White" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't Asp.net Controls. Add the `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="login_username" class="field required" title="Please provide your username" onclick="return login_username_onclick()" runat="server"/>
```

Or you can add Asp.net controls:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="login_username" CssClass="field required" ToolTip="Please provide your username"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

your inputs for username and password are html only - they need a runat="server" tag to get them in the code behind.  The usual way is to use an asp:Textbox though.